# JavaScript variables importing via <input>, processing and exporting

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
            body {  
                margin: 0;
                background: #595959;
                height: 100%;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }
            #input {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 50vh;
                margin-left: 3vw;
                bottom: 70%;
            }
            #output {
                position: absolute;
                font: small-caps bold 24px/1 sans-serif;
                bottom: 50vh;
            }
            <script>

            calculus() {

            floor_height = 0
        
            height_input_code = document.getAttributeById("height_input").value

            floor_height = height_input_code / 2.7

            console.log('This height is approximately', floor_height, 'floors of a regular living building', target='output')

            }

            </script>
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<div id="input">
    <input type="number" step="any" id="height_input" style="margin:0; width: 1000px; height: 50px; font-size:2vw; border: solid 2px black">
    <button type="button" onClick="calculus()" placeholder="✓" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin:0; font-size:1vw; border: solid 2px black">
</div>
<div id="output">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've been trying to do a somewhat of a converter but i dont know how to submit variables through button and process them.

I tried 'attaching'  to , after which is pressed, the code outputs an equivalent of meters in floors of a building for demonstration, but the log says that "calculus() is not defined", though it is cleadly in the  and named accordingly. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to define it as `function calculus()`.

Comment: Thank you so much, the puzzle has finally assembled! Didn't notice those silly mistakes, but you definetly passed on some experience to me, so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some errors on your code.

Firstly, your script is inside the style tag, but it shoud be outside.

Secondly, to define the function calculus you should use the function keyword `function calculus() {}`.

Thirdly, if you want to write the text into the output element, yous can not use the `console.log` function.

Finally, you should use `getElementById` instead of `getAttributeById` to fetch the element and then get the value.

The final code should be the next one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0;
                background: #595959;
                height: 100%;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                overflow-x: hidden;
            }

            #input {
                position: absolute;
                margin-top: 50vh;
                margin-left: 3vw;
                bottom: 70%;
            }

            #output {
                position: absolute;
                font: small-caps bold 24px/1 sans-serif;
                bottom: 50vh;
            }
        </style>

        <script>

            function calculus() {

                floor_height = 0

                height_input_code = document.getElementById("height_input").value

                floor_height = height_input_code / 2.7

                document.getElementById("output").textContent = 'This height is approximately ' + floor_height + ' floors of a regular living building'

            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="input">
            <input type="number" step="any" id="height_input" style="margin:0; width: 1000px; height: 50px; font-size:2vw; border: solid 2px black">
            <button type="button" onClick="calculus()" placeholder="✓" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; margin:0; font-size:1vw; border: solid 2px black">
        </div>
        <div id="output">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make your style and your script tags separate

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyles.css" media="screen" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <style>
        body {  
            margin: 0;
            background: #595959;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        #input {
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: 50vh;
            margin-left: 3vw;
            bottom: 70%;
        }
        #output {
            position: absolute;
            font: small-caps bold 24px/1 sans-serif;
            bottom: 50vh;
        }
    </style>
        <script>

        calculus() {

        floor_height = 0
    
        height_input_code = document.getAttributeById("height_input").value

        floor_height = height_input_code / 2.7

        console.log('This height is approximately', floor_height, 'floors of a regular living building', target='output')

        }

        </script>
```

2 function `compute` needs to be defined as

`function compute(e) {`

3 You can't use console.log to send your log to an html element. Here's how to do it

```
document.getElementById("output").textContent = floor_height;
```